# Error in mineflayer: Unsupported brand channel name

Tags: javascript, node.js, minecraft, mineflayer

I'm trying to make a mineflayer bot but it seems to keep sending the same error. Here is the code:

```
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer')

const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: ,
  username: 'Test_Bot'
})
```

And here is the error:

```
Error: Unsupported brand channel name
    at getBrandCustomChannelName (/Users/jeonghunchae/Desktop/Bots/node_modules/mineflayer/lib/plugins/game.js:22:11)
    at inject (/Users/jeonghunchae/Desktop/Bots/node_modules/mineflayer/lib/plugins/game.js:67:24)
    at /Users/jeonghunchae/Desktop/Bots/node_modules/mineflayer/lib/plugin_loader.js:41:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at injectPlugins (/Users/jeonghunchae/Desktop/Bots/node_modules/mineflayer/lib/plugin_loader.js:40:16)
    at EventEmitter.onInjectAllowed (/Users/jeonghunchae/Desktop/Bots/node_modules/mineflayer/lib/plugin_loader.js:12:5)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Client.next (/Users/jeonghunchae/Desktop/Bots/node_modules/mineflayer/lib/loader.js:124:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
jeonghunchae@2015017 Bots %
```

Is there any way how I can fix this error?

First I tried to make a lan server in my world and it sent this error. Then I created a private server with online-mod: false but it still sent the same error.

Comment: Did you actually provide a port?

Comment: Yup, I inserted the port.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem.

After a lot of research I found that I was not sure if my minecraft Version(1.19.2) was supported by Mineflayer.

After switching to 1.19 the error Message was gone.